# Unable to load native library when running titanium android app

Tags: android, titanium, native

I'm building an Android app using Titanium.
My Android module `com.tgl.androidmodule` includes a native lib called `libAlibrary-jni.so`.

In my .apk, the native libs are present in their correct folders (lib/armeabi, lib/armeabi-v7a, lib/x86) but I still get an error when trying to load the library dynamically :`System.loadLibrary("Alibrary-jni");`

Here is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
11-12 08:46:00.654: D/dalvikvm(381): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:00.669: D/AndroidmoduleModule(381): (main) [18,433] inside onAppCreate
11-12 08:46:00.669: D/dalvikvm(381): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libAlibrary-jni.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:00.719: D/dalvikvm(381): Added shared lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:00.719: D/dalvikvm(381): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x41e407e8, skipping init
11-12 08:46:00.719: D/dalvikvm(381): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:00.879: D/dalvikvm(381): Added shared lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:01.039: D/dalvikvm(381): Added shared lib /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libAlibrary-jni.so 0x41e407e8
11-12 08:46:01.054: D/dalvikvm(381): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.fw.test/lib/libgeniusscanlibrary-jni.so 0x41e407e8, skipping init
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381): (KrollRuntimeThread) [345,345] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load com.tgl.androidmodule: findLibrary returned null; Titanium 3.1.3,2013/09/18 12:01,222f4d1
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load com.tgl.androidmodule: findLibrary returned null
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:114)
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:81)
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:175)
11-12 08:46:01.959: E/TiApplication(381):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your custom library **was** found and loaded, but it seems the Titanium stuff has exception handling which obscures the true error that is occurring.  One possibility is that the native function names do not match the expected java class names, another is that it is trying to load still another library which is missing.  But we really need to know more details than the custom exception handler here is giving.  You may have to examine the source code, or take the problem up with someone who has access to that if you do not.  strace or the ndk debugger could be another option.

Comment: Yes @ChrisStratton, it seems you're right (the library is correctly loaded) since the method `onAppCreate` in my module is correctly executed and that happens before the module loading. It also seems my native function names are correct because when I call methods from `libAlibrary-jni.so` in `onAppCreate`, they are successfully executed.

Comment: You should probably pursue this with Titanium support, unless you can provide the source code of that exception handler and what it protects.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It was indeed a Titanium problem (see my answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this issue had nothing to do with my C++ lib, it was a pure Titanium problem. I understood thanks to this [Jira issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-923?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) that I only needed to install `gperf` to solve this issue. No need to say the error message was misleading. Thanks to Chris Stratton for his help.